# How does a rocking arm voltage regulator work?

Tags: voltage-regulator, electromagnetism, vintage

I am trying to determine the suitability of replacing a (ancient) rocking arm voltage regulator with a modern digital device.

I assume a rocking arm regulator has an electromechanical or magnetic feedback mechanism, but I have not been able to find a detailed description of its operation or much information on how quickly such regulators respond to transients.

Does anyone with experience have an explanation of how they work? Are these devices mag-amp based? Are they known by any other names?

Comment: Do you mean generator instead of voltage regulator?

Comment: I'm not sure... The term I encountered was 'regulator', but I have not seen the generator in person. Would a rocking-arm generator have an integrated regulator, leading to a confused description?

Comment: I know automatic (self winding) watches mostly for mechanical watches, but there should be some that generate electricity for their batteries. It would make no sense to have a device that regulates the voltage of a (primary) battery by arm movement. I doub that they have any regulator in there as watches are generally aimed at top efficiency.

Comment: Are you talking about a regulator for the generator on old cars or trucks?  Or something else?

Comment: I found an informal description [here](https://www.smokstak.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39200); it's the third or fourth answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pete Becker](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402566/how-does-a-rocking-arm-voltage-regulator-work/402598#comment989855_402566) found a good description on [this forum](https://www.smokstak.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39200), to wit:

> Inside the voltage regulator you'll find an array of carbon segments arranged in a semi-circle. A pivoting arm rocks back and forth across the carbon segments (hence the name "rocking contact").
>
> A spring tends to set the adjustment arm in a position for minimum resistance (= more field current = more output voltage.) The tension of this spring is counteracted by an electromagnet that moves the adjustment arm in a manner to raise resistance in response to the generator voltage. Sort of like a giant rheostat, but the arm compresses the carbon segments instead of just sweeping across them.
>
> In other words, No/low voltage - spring pushes the arm for minimum resistance. High voltage - electromagnet (connected to generator output) counteracts spring for more resistance. Correct voltage - spring and electromagnet tension are equal, arm stays where it is. A dashpot or some other form of 'shock absorber' is usually used to damp the movement of the arm.
>
> *— [B.Sparks](https://www.smokstak.com/forum/member.php?u=2300)*

Response speed is going to be controlled by the mechanical inertia of the parts, combined with the action of the dashpot (if any).

Replacing this with an electronic circuit should be straightforward. You need a transistor that can handle the field current and voltage, and a comparator that monitors the output voltage relative to a setpoint to drive it. Be conservative with gain and bandwidth — stability is the key here. You don't want this going into oscillation or even exhibiting any significant overshoot.